# Python dictionary of dictionaries get only primary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries and want to get the Primary keys of it only.
There is no way to eliminate the other keys by name.

That is an example dictionary:

```
{
'default': {
    'routes': '3',
    'paths': '3',
    'best_paths': {
        'broadcast': '3'
    },
    'backup_paths': {}
        },
'management': {
    'routes': '15',
    'paths': '15',
    'best_paths': {
        'local': '1',
        'direct': '1',
        'static': '1',
        'eigrp': '5'
    },
    'backup_paths': {}
        },
'test1': {
    'routes': '260',
    'paths': '275',
    'best_paths': {
        'local': '16',
        'direct': '16',
        'static': '1',
        'ospf': '33',
    },
    'backup_paths': {}
    },
}
```

The number of keys could be different. But the depths of dictionaries is always the same.

My expected result would be something like this

```
key_list = 'default', 'management', 'test1'
```

The answer of the question 'python JSON only get keys in first level' is not working.

Comment: `list(your_dictionary)` would give you that. There is nothing special about the values being dictionaries too here.

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: list(your_dict) or your_dict.keys() is enough for this.

Comment: I tried dict.keys() and got all keys as output 'default', 'routes', 'paths' ...

Comment: Just tried list(dict) as well and it's the same output 'default', 'routes', 'paths' ...

Comment: The question got marked as duplicate but the result there is not working in my program. How can I get rid of the Duplicate marking that the question is open again?

Comment: Well, it would help if you would fix your example to show the bad behavior ... I did x = {your dictionary}; list(x.keys()) returns ['management', 'default', 'test1']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Keys function will give required output

```
dic={
'default': {
    'routes': '3',
    'paths': '3',
    'best_paths': {
        'broadcast': '3'
    },
    'backup_paths': {}
        },
'management': {
    'routes': '15',
    'paths': '15',
    'best_paths': {
        'local': '1',
        'direct': '1',
        'static': '1',
        'eigrp': '5'
    },
    'backup_paths': {}
        },
'test1': {
    'routes': '260',
    'paths': '275',
    'best_paths': {
        'local': '16',
        'direct': '16',
        'static': '1',
        'ospf': '33',
    },
    'backup_paths': {}
    },
}
print (dic.keys())
```

Comment: I tried the keys function but I got all keys including subkeys as a result.

Comment: you mean dic.keys() keys giving all keys ? what is python version ? In Python2.7 the above code gives only keys of main dictionary

Comment: Version is Python 3.6.2

Comment: I tried in 3.6.2 and it works perfectly fine. Can you plz copy paste the code in my answer and let me know the result ?